# Registro ya creado en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento para validar si ya se encuentra creado un registro, lo que creo que hago es que declaro una variable res y luego hago un if exist para determinar si existe el registro y luego de acuerdo así existe o no, realizo su respectiva inserción.
Pero al crear el procedimiento me indica que la variable res no ha sido declarada.

Pero al ejecutarla me regresa null

Mi procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddRevisionRamos`(_fecha nvarchar(45),  _evaluador nvarchar(45),  _codigo nvarchar(3),  _nramo nvarchar(1),  _ma nvarchar(1),  _pc nvarchar(1),  _tt nvarchar(1),  _tr nvarchar(1), _td nvarchar(1), _tc nvarchar(1),  _ca nvarchar(1),  _fito nvarchar(1),  _sc nvarchar(1),  _cap nvarchar(1),  _observaciones nvarchar(45),  _finca nvarchar(45),  _semana nvarchar(2),  _operario nvarchar(45),  _supervisor nvarchar(45),  _bloque nvarchar(3), _idApp nvarchar(18))
BEGIN
    #select @res;  
    select @res = if (EXISTS (
    select * from reg_evaluacion where _idApp = @idApp),1,0);

    if @res = 1 then
        INSERT INTO `revisionramos`.`reg_evaluacion` (`FECHA`, `EVALUADOR`, `CODIGO`, `NRAMO`, `MA`, `PC`, `TT`, `TR`, `TD`, `TC`, `CA`, `FITO`, `SC`, `CAP`, `OBSERVACIONES`, `FINCA`, `SEMANA`, `OPERARIO`, `SUPERVISOR`, `BLOQUE`) 
        VALUES (_fecha, _evaluador, _codigo, _nramo, _ma, _pc, _tt, _tr, _td, _tc, _ca, _fito, _sc, _cap, _observaciones, _finca, _semana, _operario, _supervisor, _bloque);
    end if;
END
```

y estos son los campos de mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno vamos por parte, `@idApp` no veo exista en tu contexto actual; a salvedad en la misma conexión la estes declarando desde fuera de la llamada a su **SP**; veo existe `_idApp` y *con ella te propongo lo siguiente*:

Cambia:

```
select @res = if (EXISTS (
    select * from reg_evaluacion where _idApp = @idApp),1,0);

if @res = 1 then
    INSERT INTO `revisionramos`.`reg_evaluacion` (`FECHA`, `EVALUADOR`, `CODIGO`, `NRAMO`, `MA`, `PC`, `TT`, `TR`, `TD`, `TC`, `CA`, `FITO`, `SC`, `CAP`, `OBSERVACIONES`, `FINCA`, `SEMANA`, `OPERARIO`, `SUPERVISOR`, `BLOQUE`) 
        VALUES (_fecha, _evaluador, _codigo, _nramo, _ma, _pc, _tt, _tr, _td, _tc, _ca, _fito, _sc, _cap, _observaciones, _finca, _semana, _operario, _supervisor, _bloque);
end if;
```

por:

```
DECLARE res INT(11);
/* PUEDES USAR UNA DE LAS DOS SIGUIENTES INSTRUCCIONES */
-- Ésta
SET res=(select count(*) from reg_evaluacion where [aqui el campo de tu tabla que corresponde] = _idApp);
-- o ésta
select count(*) INTO res from reg_evaluacion where [aqui el campo de tu tabla que corresponde] = _idApp;

if res = 1 then
    INSERT INTO `revisionramos`.`reg_evaluacion` (`FECHA`, `EVALUADOR`, `CODIGO`, `NRAMO`, `MA`, `PC`, `TT`, `TR`, `TD`, `TC`, `CA`, `FITO`, `SC`, `CAP`, `OBSERVACIONES`, `FINCA`, `SEMANA`, `OPERARIO`, `SUPERVISOR`, `BLOQUE`) 
        VALUES (_fecha, _evaluador, _codigo, _nramo, _ma, _pc, _tt, _tr, _td, _tc, _ca, _fito, _sc, _cap, _observaciones, _finca, _semana, _operario, _supervisor, _bloque);
END IF;
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

No confundas las variables de sesión (las que inician con arroba) con las locales (ya sea de `DECLARE` o que pasas por parámetros).

Comment: Roberto, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta , en efecto ya lo comprendí mejor y me funcionó.